# Mongoose user.save() doesn't return updated _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple code that uses mongoose with nodejs to save a user object but when I log the result object that is return from save() method it is just the object I sent and the _id and id values are undefined.
Still, the object is saved correctly in the database with the new _id.

this is my code
`

```
import { mongoose } from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

export const addUser = async (_user) => {
    let user = new User({ ..._user });
    let result;
    try {
        result = await user.save();
        console.log(result._id);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return result;
};
```

`
I expect console.log(result._id) to have the new generated Id but it is undefined even though it is saved correctly to the database

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to assign the _id before calling save()

```
export const addUser = async (_user) => {
let user = new User({ ..._user });
user._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
let result;
try {
    result = await user.save();
    console.log(result._id);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
return result;
```

};